# How to write C make file

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I'm new to C programming. I want to compile C program using Make file. I can compile the source code file with the command:

```
gcc `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -o xmlexample readelementsfile.c
```

But when I create make file and I add the above commend into the make file I get this error:

```
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Can you tell me where I'm wrong?

Comment: The first thing you did wrong was not post your make file. :-) You gave us the compiler command line and the make error code, but not what you put in the make file. Please edit and add that as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify a target:

```
all:
    gcc `xml2-config --cflags --libs` -o xmlexample readelementsfile.c
```

The whitespace at the start of the second line should be a <kbd>Tab</kbd> character.

You can also specify dependencies so that not all of your commands are run every time you build.

**Related**

- [Makefile Tutorial](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/)

Comment: Now I get this error: `gmake: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.` Maybe again I'm missing something?

Comment: @user1285928: The tutorial I linked to where it shows an example with a target called `clean`. Also you don't need to actually need to `make clean`. Just use `make` or `make all`. That does what you need. You only need `make clean` when you want to remove the built files. It's not necessary here.